Why Capacitor can't behave like smoothing DC effect in AC motor Phase shift application?
Capacitors in AC-to-DC power supply will work as smoothing after Diodes, which means it is charging on Positive peek, and will store charge on decrement of Peek, so it is providing smoothing DC Output.
But on the other hand when Capacitor is used in AC Phase Shift application in Single Phase AC motors, the capacitor got discharge on decrement of peek of half cycle. Why it can't store charge like in DC smoothing application in this scenerio?

Your AC Phase Shift example has no diodes. Its capacitor does store charge momentarily each cycle, but capacitor average voltage over many cycles is zero. Your AC-to-DC example must include diode(s), which cause a DC voltage across the capacitor.

but the DC voltage after diode is pulsating DC which is similar to Positive peek of AC Half Cycle, Capacitor store charge on pulsating DC but not on AC?
